# Fetch with webpack - strange error

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am getting error when I use `fetch` library with webpack and react. It does not want to parse json file , altough it works on other json loaders like d3.json. It throws

> parsing failed SyntaxError: Unexpected token /

Comment: Please provide more info such as code that invoke `fetch` and request's response.

Comment: I menaged to solve this by making new gist with json data wich I cleaned a little. Probably it was typo because json was generated with phpmyadmin plugin wich had a lot of slashes. tnx for comment